# Android app to display and log sensor data

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming and i'm trying to understand the control flow in android programs. I've been working on a program to log and display sensor data.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener
```

This is the main class with `onCreate()`, `btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(), btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(), onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` which do most of the important tasks.

`onCreate()` has all this code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleView);

    acc_x = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_x_values);
    acc_y = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_y_values);
    acc_z = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_z_values);

    x = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_x);
    y = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_y);
    z = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc_z);

    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType), 20000);
```

And the start and stop button funtionalities are defined here.

```
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startFlag = true;
            String storepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            System.out.println("Stored at" +storepath);   // /storage/sdcard
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Started Recording Data and Storing at"+storepath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                myFile = new File(storepath + "/GaitApp/" + name.getText() + "_acc.csv");
                myFile.createNewFile();

                fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(myOutWriter);
                myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(myBufferedWriter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
        } //onclick
    }); //startbutton

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Stopped Recording",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startFlag = false;
            try {
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// onClick
    }); // btnstopButton

onSensorChanged() is:



    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            if(startFlag){

            float[] values = event.values;
            // Movement
            float x_float = values[0];
            float y_float = values[1];
            float z_float = values[2];

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 20) {
                long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
                lastUpdate = curTime;

                x_float = event.values[0];
                y_float = event.values[1];
                z_float = event.values[2];


            acc_x.setText(Float.toString(x_float));
            acc_y.setText(Float.toString(y_float));
            acc_z.setText(Float.toString(z_float));

            String res=String.valueOf(currentDateandTime+", "+x_float)+", "+String.valueOf(y_float)+", "+String.valueOf(z_float+"\n");
            Log.d("test", res);

            for (int i = 0; i % 1 == 0; i++) {
                if (startFlag) {

                    try{
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(myOutWriter);
                    myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(myBufferedWriter);
                    myPrintWriter.append(curTime - lastUpdate + ", " + x_float + ", " + y_float + ", " + z_float+ "\n");


                    }
                    catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
                    }

                  //myPrintWriter.write(curTime - lastUpdate + ", " + x_float + ", " + y_float + ", " + z_float+ "\n");
                } //startFlag is true

                else {  
                        try {
                            myOutWriter.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            fOut.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } // catch
                } // else
            } //for
         } // if -- time
       } // startFlag
      } //accelerometer -- sensor
      } // onSensorChanged
```

I'm trying to understand how the `onSensorChanged()` transfers control and in the process the acceleration data to `onCreate()` to be displayed and stored.

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreate` method is only used to initially setup the view.  Updates to the display must occur by deliberately invoking them.  Furthermore updates to the UI must occur on the UI thread.  Since the `onSensorChanged` call can occur asynchronously, if you wish sensor updates to trigger a display update you must send yourself a UI thread event. One option is to use a handler such as in the following untested code.

```
private Handler mHandler;

public void onCreate() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        saveData(event);
        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (isResumed() && currentTime > (lasttime + SOME_DELAY)) {
            lasttime = currentTime;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateDisplay(event);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private void updateDisplay(SensorEvent event) {
    acc_x.setText(...);
    acc_y.setText(...);
    acc_z.setText(...);
    x.setText(...);
    y.setText(...);
    z.setText(...);
}
```

Depending on your application you may wish to log your data in a service.

Answer (score 0):

onSensorChanged() is the handler in this case. This call back function takes care of updating the UI and writing to the file.